# C# Event handler errors with classes and context

Tags: c#, class

When I have a button click change the value of a label to the name of a class object, I get the error

> "The name 'maxwell' does not exist in the current context"

Can anyone tell me how I can refer to the data members of an object that I have created?  I want the dog that I created to be accessible across my whole application and by all of the buttons in my application.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public class Dog
    {
        string name;
        int length;
        public Dog(string nm)
        {
            name = nm;
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Dog maxwell = new Dog("Maxwell"); 
        Dog fred = new Dog("Fred");
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LabelName.Content = maxwell.name;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The scope of variable `maxwell` is limited to the method `MainWindow` -- move the variable declaration to be a class level property of `class MainWindow` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

You want to declare `maxwell` as a [field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in your class `MainWindow`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public class Dog
    {
        string name;
        int length;
        public Dog(string nm)
        {
            name = nm;
        }
    }

    private Dog maxwell;
    private Dog fred;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        maxwell = new Dog("Maxwell"); 
        fred = new Dog("Fred");
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LabelName.Content = maxwell.name;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is more progressive approach.
Note that methods of the class have only access to the properties declared in the class scope/body

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{   
    // Inner Classes 

    public class Dog
    {
        private string name;
        public string Name {
           get{ return this.name };
           set{ this.name = value}'
        }

        private int length;
        public int Length {
           get{ return this.length };
           set{ this.length = value}'
        }

        public Dog( string _name )
        {
            this.name = _name;
        }
    }

    // Properties

    // For storing dogs
    private Dicionary<string, Dog> Dogs;


    // Methods

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // New dictionary of dogs
        Dogs = new Dictionary<string, Dog>();

        // adding Dogs objects
        Dogs.add("maxwell", new Dog("Maxwell)); 
        Dogs.add("fred", new Dog("Fred"));

    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LabelName.Content = Dogs["maxwell"].Name;
        LabelLength.Content = Dogs["maxwell"].Length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you are welcome, could you please +1 for this solution I'm trying to get some reputation points up in here :)